# How to make a usb connection within an android app

Tags: android, usb, synchronization

has anyone an idea how to make an usb-connection in an android ap to a Desktop Applicaktion? some data has to be synced when the device is connected via USB... - by workflow this may not be done over the air :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the release of android 3.2 this has been changed - USB becomes supported :)
[Link: Android SDK USB handling changed](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.1.html#usb)

Comment: link broken.. you should explain what the link talks about and not only vomit them, in order to prevent these situations.

Answer (score 1):

USB is not part of the APIs exposed by the Android SDK, sorry.